# Asp.net mvc crud operation datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Hi i have simple MVC with crud operation the problem starting always if i try to put a `datepicker` (that i did not get it either work), in that field

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
```

The `datepicker` is from https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ the problem is that the field model.Age is part of a form with class`"form-control"` so i must add second class to give to the datepicker?
in my index file i have a lot of scripts  look the script that for datepicker`

```
function PopupForm(url) {
            var formDiv = $('<div/>');
            $.get(url)
            .done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);

                Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: 'Fill Employee Details',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 700,
                    close: function () {
                        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }

                });
            });
    }
    function datepicker (){
        $(".example").datepicker();

    };
```

`

Is below from another function the question is on the datepicker function on .example if i add a new class same and call from the `model.age` isn't working the `datepicker`,
and the worst scenario is that the application after of several tries lost the pagination and i lost the original view of the site.

All Index

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee List";
}

<h2>Employee CRUD Operations</h2>

<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px" onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action(" AddOrEdit","Employee")')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</a>
<table id="employeeTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section scripts{
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var Popup, dataTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            dataTable =  $("#employeeTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Employee/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Position" },
                    { "data": "Office" },
                    { "data": "Age" },
                    { "data": "Salary" },
                    {"data":"EmployeeID" , "render" : function (data) {
                        return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Employee")/" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete("+data+")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
                    },
                        "orderable": false,
                        "searchable":false,
                        "width":"150px"
                    }

                ],
                "language": {

                    "emptyTable" : "No data found, Please click on <b>Add New</b> Button"
                }
            });
        });

        function PopupForm(url) {
            var formDiv = $('<div/>');
            $.get(url)
            .done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);

                Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: 'Fill Employee Details',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 700,
                    close: function () {
                        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }

                });
            });
    }
    function datepicker (){
        $(".example").datepicker();

    };

        function SubmitForm(form) {
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            if($(form).valid()){
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : form.action,
                    data : $(form).serialize(),
                    success : function (data) {
                        if(data.success)
                        {
                            Popup.dialog('close');
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();

                            $.notify(data.message,{
                                globalPosition :"top center",
                                className : "success"
                            })

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }

        function Delete(id) {
            if(confirm('Are You Sure to Delete this Employee Record ?'))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Delete","Employee")/' + id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success)
                        {
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();

                            $.notify(data.message, {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "success"
                            })

                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }
</script>
}
```

and the all addoredit model that includes the form and the model.age.

```
@model Asp.NETMVCCRUD.Models.Employee
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new {onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Position, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Position, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Position)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Office, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Office, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"  />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn" />
    </div>
}
```

I want to restore my site on the original view, and the second is that i want a `datepicker` on the `mode.age` `textbox`!

Comment: Since you have `$(".example").datepicker();`, just add the class name to corresponding `EditorFor`: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control example" } })`. No need to use special functions to define datepicker, putting it in `$(document).ready()` should be enough.

Comment: this dialog (formDiv.dialog) is bootstrap or jqueryUI?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you don't call your function datepicker()!, you have to call it after making sure that the dialog opened, and its content displayed.
Based on used jquery library to open the form in popup (dialog), you will use the event of after displaying and call your function datepicker() in its handler.

For adding multiple class to the same element you can do the following

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control example" } })
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I tried Nothings happened look my new example above that i put the script inside the form